# ArcGis locator task vs REST call has different results

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-android-api

I am using the android and iOS sdks to perform a geocode request to the server.
When I am calling the same endpoint using REST I get different results back.

In my case the REST call has way more results.

iOS code:

```swift
        let locatorTask = AGSLocatorTask(url: URL(string: "https://my-server/services/GeocodeServer/")!)
        
        let params = AGSGeocodeParameters()
        params.maxResults = payload.maxSuggestions
        params.countryCode = "DE"
        params.outputSpatialReference = .wgs84()
        params.resultAttributeNames = ["*"]

        locatorTask.geocode(withSearchText: payload.searchQuery, parameters: params) {
          // handle result
        }
```

REST call:

`https://my-server/services/GeocodeServer/suggest?f=json&text=SomeStreet`

It would be nice to know what request url the iOS lib generates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my response to your question on Esri Community: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-ios-questions/arcgis-locator-task-vs-rest-call-has-different/m-p/1200868/highlight/true#M7422